# How does an Azure web app handle static variables?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, azure-web-app-service, .net-6.0

I have an API-application which logs information to sharepoint. In order to connect to sharepoint i use a token. The token expires after 12 to 24 Hours. So i need to update the token when needed.

I tried to store the token in a static variable in my Sharepoint Class. When the token expires i request a new one and store it back to my static variable. This works fine localy.

When i deploy the Webservice in azure, it generates a new token for each request. I am not sure how to store the token in a way that it is only updated when it has to.

I am confused and asume that maybe on each call the application is builded from 0 and the token gets lost.

Any help is appreciated

```
`public class MySharePointService : IMySharepointService
    {
        private readonly IMyLogService _myLogService;
        
        private static string _spToken = string.Empty;
.....
       private async Task GenerateAccessTokenIfNeeded()
        {
            var newToken = "";
            try
            {
                using (var context = new AuthenticationManager().GetAccessTokenContext(_siteUrl, _spToken))
                {
                    context.ExecuteQuery();
                }
                return;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"Token {_spToken} didn't work. A new one will be generated");
                Trace.TraceInformation($"Token {_spToken} didn't work. A new one will be generated");
                _myLogService.Log("SharepointService", "GenerateAccessTokenIfNeeded", "Information", $"New token generation");

                try
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_siteUrl) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(_clientId) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(_clientSecret))
                    {
                        _myLogService.Log("SharepointService", "GenerateAccessTokenIfNeeded", "Error", $"New token generation failed beacause the environment variables where empty");
                        return;
                    }

                    using (var context = new AuthenticationManager().GetACSAppOnlyContext(_siteUrl, _clientId, _clientSecret))
                    {
                        newToken = context.GetAccessToken();
                    }

                    _spToken = newToken;
                    Debug.WriteLine($"New sp Token {_spToken}");
                    Trace.TraceInformation($"New sp Token {_spToken}");
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Failed generating access token: " +e);
                    Trace.TraceError("Failed generating access token: " +e);
                    _myLogService.Log("SharepointService", "GenerateAccessTokenIfNeeded", "Error", $"New token generation failed");
                }
            }
        }
    }  
...`
```

I set my application in Azure in always on.

Comment: I solved my problem my self. I found out that i had a scale out with 11 instances. That's why it generated a new token because it went to another instance. I will let the question here for other people with the same problem.

Comment: One of the reasons statics are evil, especially when multiple instances are involved. Either look for a distributed cache or accept that the content can be different per instance.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem my self. I found out that i had a scale out with 11 instances. That's why it generated a new token because it went to another instance. I will let the question here for other people with the same problem.